# Why is this bash prompt acting strangely/disappearing, and how do I fix it (OS X)?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, prompt

I admit that I use a somewhat long-winded bash prompt:

```
--(username)-(Wed April 01|12:00:00)--(~ $
```

Recently, I got the bright idea to change it so that depending on the exit value from the previous command, if success, the interior elements of the ()'s would be green, and if failure, they would be red.  I got it working for the most part (some odd exit statuses will change the color to something else, but I'm ok with it), but when typing a command which is more than one line, and causes the terminal to scroll, the prompt disappears!  My prompt worked fine when there was no color, so I'm guessing it is related to my color escaping, and particularly my unclosed ['s, but I can't pin it down.

```
#.profile
export PS1='--(\e[$((32-${?}))m\u\e[0m)-(\e[$((32-${?}))m\d\e[0m|\e[$((32-${?}))m\T\e[0m)--(\e[$((32-${?}))m\w\e[0m \$ '
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It sounds like [this](http://forums.macosxhints.com/archive/index.php/t-17068.html) should solve your problem.

This seems to work for me`*`:

```
export PS1='--(\[\e[$((32-${?}))m\]\u\[\e[0m\])-(\[\e[$((32-${?}))m\]\d\[\e[0m\]|\[\e[$((32-${?}))m\]\T\[\e[0m\])--(\[\e[$((32-${?}))m\]\w\[\e[0m\] \$ '
```

`*` well, really `export PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '` works for me

To quote the linked post, the answer lies in adding **\[ and \]** around all of your color sequences in your PS1 declaration:

> Before I had the following value for PS1:
>
> '\e[0;34m\h:\w [!]\$\e[0m '
>
> which gave me a nice blue prompt of the following form
>
> hostname:working-directory [command-number]$
>
> However, I had the same line-wrapping problem you did. The fix was to insert \[ and \] around the ANSI escapes so that the shell knows not to include them in the line wrapping calculation. This results in the following value for PS1:
>
> '\[\e[0;34m\]\h:\w [!]\$\[\e[m\] '

Comment: Chas, just looking at that prompt makes my eyes red.  Thank you for your help, sir!  Yours was the only solution that seemed to work completely.

Comment: After changing the color of my prompt (in Linux, not OSX), I was having trouble with searching backwards in my history.  This solved my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053 -- I have a fancy prompt with colors, and now bash doesn't seem to know how wide my terminal is.  Lines wrap around incorrectly.

By the way; for your reference; here's my `PS1` which looks like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [lyndir.com](http://lhunath.lyndir.com/stuff/PS1.png))</sub>

```
\[$reset$bold$green\]\u@\h\[$blue\] \W \[$red\]${?/#0/\[$green\]}\$\[$reset\]
```

Notice how I put all the color codes in `$parameters` to make it neater, but more importantly, because **you should be using `tput` to generate them**. See:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/037 -- How can I print text in various colors?

I declare my color parameters in a utility script that gets sourced by [my `~/.bashrc`](http://lhunath.lyndir.com/stuff/.bashrc) (and any scripts I write) which is called [`bashlib`](http://lhunath.lyndir.com/stuff/bashlib).

On a final note; put your `PS1` definition in `~/.bashrc` and don't `export` it.  There's absolutely no reason why you should add your `PS1` definition to the environment of any and all processes you spawn from your shell.

Answer (score 2):

You just seem to be missing the start and end brackets around your escapes (before the first '\e' and after the last 'm'):

```
PS1='--(\[\e[$((32-${?}))m\u\e[0m)-(\e[$((32-${?}))m\d\e[0m|\e[$((32-${?}))m\T\e[0m)--(\e[$((32-${?}))m\w\e[0m\] \$ '
```

As mentioned, the PS1 var does not need to be exported:  only your shell needs to see it.