# Why does the ruby console arbitrarily move the cursor to the beginning of the line and overwrite the line

Tags: ruby, irb, pry

When i use the rails console in Ubuntu 14.04, the program will sometimes randomly move the cursor back to the beginning of the line, furthermore if i press enter then up, the cursor will move up a line and delete the above line
things i have tried:

- Using Xterm, Terminator and the Gnome terminal
- Using IRB and PRY

the behaviour is identical despite the above

For example:

```
[90] pry(main)> PaperTrail::VersionAssociation.where(foreign
```

becomes:

```
_key:1ry(main)> PaperTrail::VersionAssociation.where(foreign
```

when I would assume it to become:

```
[90] pry(main)> PaperTrail::VersionAssociation.where(foreign_key:1
```

Comment: what are the values of your `$TERM` and `$COLUMNS` variables?

Comment: --------------------- xterm

Comment: maybe you have a funky prompt? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133031/shell-prompt-line-wrapping-issue