# Bash prompt does not wrap text properly

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I recently added some color to my bash prompt, and now when I type a command the text doesn't wrap properly.

Here is an example:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ williamgiles$
long commandwilliamgiles$ this is a really long command,this is a really
```

My original PS1:

```
\h:\W \u\$
```

My new one with color:

```
\e[0;35m\h:\W \u$ \e[m
```

Comment: There are _many_ other questions about this same problem on the site -- even though they're arguably off-topic here (as questions about configuring your system _as a user_, as opposed to developing software, are better placed at [unix.se]. See f/e [shell prompt line wrapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133031/shell-prompt-line-wrapping-issue), [Why is this bash prompt acting strangely / disappearing and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706750) -- and, outside this site, [BashFAQ #53](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the color-changing sequences as something that does not contribute to the length of the prompt on-screen.

```
PS1='\[\e[0;35m\]\h:\W \u$ \[\e[m\]'
```

`bash` already knows to take the expansion of `\h`, `\W`, and `\u` into account; it has no idea that `\e[0;35m` is not simply 7 characters that the terminal will display on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @chepner's answer, I personally use `\1` and `\2` in my `.inputrc`
Here's an example:

```
set vi-ins-mode-string \1\e[38;5;015m\2╰─\1\e[0m\2\1\e[38;2;191;254;33m\2(ins)⫸\1\e[0m\2\1\e[5 q\2\1\e]12;rgb:bf/fe/21\e\\\2
set vi-cmd-mode-string \1\e[38;5;015m\2╰─\1\e[0m\2\1\e[38;2;191;121;33m\2(cmd)⫸\1\e[0m\2\1\e[2 q\2\1\e]12;rgb:bf/79/21\e\\\2
```

`\1` denotes the start of a zero-length section, and `\2` denotes the end.
(`\001` and `\002` also work)
I wrote a [blog post](https://orelfichman.com/blog/terminal-escape-codes-are-awesome) about the topic not long ago. You might find it interesting.

What my shell ends up looking like (The top part is possible by using [Oh-My-Posh](https://ohmyposh.dev/):

[image: my_shell]