# How to wrap color coded text to fixed line length in terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, ansi-colors, color-codes

For text with color codes, how to wrap it to a fixed length in the terminal?

Text without color codes wraps nicely with `fold`:

```
echo -e "12345678901234567890" | fold -w 10
1234567890
1234567890
```

But this red text wraps wrong:

```
echo -e "\u001b[31m12345678901234567890" | fold -w 10
12345
6789012345
67890
```

Note: While the red text is wrapped wrong, it still is printed in red, which is the desired behavior.

(My use case is line wrapping the output of `git log --color=always --oneline --graph`.)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424076/wrap-text-accounting-for-non-printing-characters

Comment: @0stone0 : Yes, that it essentially the same question there. But there is no useful answer there either.

Comment: Another version of this question is here, also without a useful answer: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594581/how-can-i-display-only-the-first-screenfull-of-output-including-all-terminal-co

Comment: Yea, I'm aware that that question has no valid solution, thought I'd share. Still wondering why you would want to 'wrap' the output of `git log --graph`. Wouldn't that destroy the 'graph' ?

Comment: echo "12345678901234567890" | sed s'/.\{10\}/echo $(tput setaf 4)&$(tput sgr 0)\n/ge'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When determining the (printable) width of a prompt (eg, `PS1`) the special characters - `\[` and `\]` - are used to designate a series of non-printing characters (see [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html), [this](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/400161) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71990220)).

So far I've been unable to find a way to use `\[` and `\]` outside the scope of a prompt hence this `awk` hack ...

---

Assumptions:

- we don't know the color codes in advance
- for this exercise it is sufficient to deal with color codes of the format `\e[...m` (`\e[m` turns off color)
- may have to deal with multiple color codes in the input

We'll wrap one `awk` idea in a `bash` function (for easier use):

```
myfold() {

awk -v n="${1:-10}" '                                                  # default wrap is 10 (printable) characters
BEGIN { regex="[[:cntrl:]][[][^m]*m"                                   # regex == "\e[*m"
       #regex="\x1b[[][^m]*m"                                          # alternatives
       #regex="\033[[][^m]*m"
      }
      { input=$0

        while (input != "" ) {                                         # repeatedly strip off "n" characters until we have processed the entire line
              count=n
              output=""

              while ( count > 0 ) {                                    # repeatedly strip off color control codes and characters until we have stripped of "n" characters
                    match(input,regex)

                    if (RSTART && RSTART <= count) {
                       output=output substr(input,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
                       input=substr(input,RSTART+RLENGTH)
                       count=count - (RSTART > 1 ? RSTART-1 : 0)
                    }
                    else {
                       output=output substr(input,1,count)
                       input=substr(input,count+1)
                       count=0
                    }
              }
              print output
        }
      }
'
}
```

**NOTES:**

- other non-color, non-printing characters will throw off the count
- the regex could be expanded to address other non-printing color and/or character codes

Test run:

```
$ echo -e "\e[31m123456789012345\e[m67890\e[32mABCD\e[m"
12345678901234567890ABCD


$ echo -e "\e[31m123456789012345\e[m67890\e[32mABCD\e[m" | myfold 10
1234567890
1234567890
ABCD


$ echo -e "\e[31m123456789012345\e[m67890\e[32mABCD\e[m" | myfold 7
1234567
8901234
567890A
BCD
```

Displaying colors:

[image]