# Linux bash line override itself

Tags: linux, bash

I made my own .bashrc (part of code below) and in test by pressed arrows up/down: i found that 
history of commands override static text of line or leaves last command and print new over it. How to fix that?

```
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

RESTORE=$(echo -en '\033[0m')
RKNAME=$(echo -en '\033[38;5;106m')
RKPATH=$(echo -en '\033[38;5;229m')
RKBRANCH=$(echo -en '\033[38;5;44m')
RKGIT=$(echo -en '\033[38;5;250m')

pathToFolder=$PWD;

if [[ $pathToFolder =~ .*_GitRepo.* ]]
then
    PS1='${RKNAME}\u@\h${RESTORE} ${RKGIT}Git ${RKPATH}\W\ ${RKBRANCH}$(parse_git_branch) \n ${RKGIT}-- $ ${RESTORE} '
    fi
```

Comment: Don't use escapes if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @123 yeap, i clear for myself problem about a lot of escapes now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve my problem is:

> However, I had the same line-wrapping problem you did. The fix was to insert [ and ] around the ANSI escapes so that the shell knows not to include them in the line wrapping calculation.

Thanks, @Gillies for link [Why is this bash prompt acting strangely/disappearing, and how do I fix it (OS X)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706750/why-is-this-bash-prompt-acting-strangely-disappearing-and-how-do-i-fix-it-os-x)