# Bash history results in uneditable string

Tags: bash

I've noticed recently in my terminal emulator that sometimes the <up> arrow to show previous commands is behaving very strangely. This is best illustrated with a repeatable example I've found:

`ls`

(This just makes sure there's some command in the history)

`git --git-dir=$HOME/.configrepo/ --work-tree=$HOME status`

(It doesn't matter what this command outputs)

Now if I press <up> my current command line changes to `git --git-dir=$HOME/.configrepo/ --work-tree=$HOME status`, but if I press it again I get `git --git-dls`.

Oddly, if I run this command it outputs the result of `ls`, and the text before `ls` cannot be edited. It's almost as if a fragment of the git command has become a part of the prompt. I originally suspected there were non-printing characters hiding somewhere in there but this happens even if I type out all the commands from scratch.

In the bash profile I have the prompt set as follows.

`PS1='\e[0;32m\w\$ \e[0m'`

In case it's relevant I'm using the macOS 11.4 Terminal application.

Comment: To see if the prompt itself has become weird, press control-L to have bash clear the window and redraw the prompt and whatever you've typed so far. If the extra junk disappears, it's not part of the prompt; if the extra junk remains, it is part of the prompt. In any case this has nothing to do with Git: it's just bash interacting badly with your Terminal (and/or some previous command).

Comment: Does the same happen if you set `PS1=""`?

Comment: Looks like your PS1 improperly handles colors and bash can't calculate cursor positions. Please show `printf "%q\n" "$PS1"`.

Comment: Thanks all. PS1="" does indeed correct the problem, and ctrl-L is showing the junk is not part of the prompt. I'll add the PS1 from my bash profile to the question since it sounds like it's very likely that.

Comment: The nonprinting sections of the prompt string (i.e. the color change escape sections) have to be surrounded by `\[...\]` so bash can tell they don't take up space on the screen. Looks to me like it should be `PS1='\[\e[0;32m\]\w\$ \[\e[0m\]'`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092488/custom-bash-prompt-is-overwriting-itself).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hints in the comments I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706750/why-is-this-bash-prompt-acting-strangely-disappearing-and-how-do-i-fix-it-os-x) which has fixed my issue. The answer was to wrap the colour sections in `\[` and `\]`. Thanks all!